# is there any practical difference between these two if() statements?

Tags: actionscript-3, if-statement

Is there any practical (faster/slower, functionality, etc) difference between these two sets of if statements?

## 1:

```
var myVar:Boolean;
if (myVar == true)
{
    //do stuff
}
//waldo:
if (myVar == false)
{
    //do other stuff
}
```

## 2:

```
var myVar:Boolean;
if (myVar == true)
{
    //do stuff
}
//waldo:
else 
{
    //do other stuff
}
```

This is specifically a question about if() statements for variables that only have two possible values (other than null), like Boolean variables.

Comment: In addition to what has been mentioned, in #2, something will **always** happen (the *else*). In #1, if `myVar == null` then nothing will happen – so the two examples are not equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. These examples are not functionally same. As @Nicolas already mentioned that `myVar` can be changed in first block and then second if statement will be true. Something like this:

   ```
   if (myVar == true)
   {
       //do stuff
       myVar = false;
   }
   if (myVar == false)
   {
       // now this will be executed
   }
   ```

This won't happen in the second case.

2. In first example boolean value is checked twice (i.e. two if statements), but in second one boolean value is checked only once. This gives a slight performance benefit. It won't be much if this is done rarely, but if this code is executed many many time per seconds (e.g. inside enter frame event for hundreds of movie clips) then performance benefit like this can become crucial. For example, if you can save 50 milliseconds per second then that will be 5 percent performance improvement.
3. In my opinion, second example is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that in the first example, if the value of `myVar` changes between the two blocks to false, the second statement will still execute. In the second example, even if `myVar` becomes false after the first block completes, the `else` clause will not be executed because the associated `if` clause has already been executed (only one of them will run).

As far as performance and code quality go, you'll usually want to use something like the second example (unless the side effects of the first example are necessary).

Comment: Can you have code between an if and else statement the way OP showed in the example? I've never tried it funnily enough so I'm curious - seems messy to me. Anyway, this answer is still 100% valid, regardless of whether or not you can.

Comment: Are you asking about how `//waldo:` is between the if and else blocks? i believe that's only legal because it's a comment, otherwise you wouldn't be able to have executable code there.

Comment: Yea thought so, I just wasn't sure if the OP had put that there to represent a block of code as done in the statements ("//do stuff").